# Simplest way to start non-react webworker from reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I have written webworker code responsible for some CPU intensive task. The worker works outside reactJS app, but trying to load it in reactJS project fails, because reactJS does not allow access to worker's JS file.

I found this code and tried it:

```
const worker = require("worker!./browser-worker.js");
```

And I got this error:

```
./src/browser-ui.js
  Line 5:  Unexpected '!' in 'worker!./browser-worker.js'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
```

I would like reactJS to run webpack on the worker code (it uses ES6 modules). How can I start web worker in reactJS?

Comment: Where did that error come from? It looks like an ESLint violation.

Comment: webpack is a development tool to bundle your application. How is react supposed to "run webpack" on the client? Also react does not "restict access to any js files". These are two completely different levels.

Comment: What you probably need is the [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) for webpack so that webpack knows how to bundle the worker into your react application.

Comment: @trixn I am totally new to React. But it seemed to me that it's running webpack or some other transpiler on background. And I need the worer code transpiled because it uses ES6 modules.

Comment: @TomášZato Then you have a misconception of how webpack works. The code that you write your react application in gets transpiled by webpack to code that your browser can understand by bundling your es6 modules into one or more js files that can then be served by your web server. webpack does only run once before your react app is even ready to use. It's a development tool and nothing that react even knows about. You could also build a react app without webpack at all. What you need is to make webpack know how to import the webworker files into your modules.

Comment: And to repeat myself: You need https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader. It's a plugin for webpack to make it know how to import the webworker code into the module you want to use it in. This is entirely a problem of *building* your app not running it.